# oracle sql - cannot export with wm_concat

Tags: sql, export, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

Even with a very simple query using wm_concat, when I want to export with sqldeveloper, I get an error saying "no column valid for export. Clob or Blob columns are not take in charge now".

What can I do to export my result ?

This is not helping : `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(`

Comment: What do you mean by 'export' - exporting a result set from the data grid, or a database export of a view? wm_concat isn't supported anyway. Can you use listagg instead, or are you stuck on an old version? Later versions of SQL Developer allow a grid export of wm_concat output (just tried in 4.1), though the generated insert isn't valid if the value is longer than 4000 chars.

Comment: Hi, I mean right click on the result and export. I also get the error with lisagg. But thanks, I'm downloading now SD 4.